# Limit as a Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need to comupte this limit by treating it as a Riemann sum
$$L := \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)}$$
So first I took the natural log from both sides to get
$$ \ln L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\ln\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\left(\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+2)+...+\ln(n+n)\right)\right)$$
which can then be written as
$$ \ln L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\frac{1}{n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+2)+...+\ln(n+n)}{n}\right)$$
And using the sigma notation
$$ \ln L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\frac{1}{n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n+k)\right)$$
Further analysing this second bit I got that since $\ln(n+k) = \ln\left(n\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right) = \ln(n) +\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)$
It would seem that I should take $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$, but I am pretty certain that I have made a mistake somewhere. Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: In the third line, you have the indeterminate form $\ln L = -\infty + \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \ln L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\ln\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\left(\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+2)+...+\ln(n+n)\right)\right)=\\\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})+\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{2}{n})+...+\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{n}{n})\right)=\\\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over n}\ln (1+{i\over n})=\int_{0}^{1}\ln (1+x) dx=(1+x)\ln (1+x)-(1+x)\Bigg|_{0}^{1}=2\ln 2-1$$therefore $$L={4\over e}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\ln L = -\ln n + \frac 1n \sum_\limits{i= n+1}^{2n} \ln i$

Consider a Riemann sum with $n$ intervals of step 1

$\sum_\limits{i= n}^{2n-1} \ln i < \int_\limits{n}^{2n} \ln x\ dx <\sum_\limits{i= n+1}^{2n} \ln i$

$\int\limits_n^{2n} \ln x\ dx = x\ln x - x|_{n}^{2n}\\
(2n\ln 2n - 2n) - (n\ln n - n)$

This is Stirling's approximation.

or more precisely Stirling's approximation says

$\ln n! \approx n\ln n - n$

Plugged into

$L = \frac 1n (\frac {2n!}{n!})^\frac 1n\\
\ln L = -\ln n + \frac 1n \ln 2n! - \frac 1n \ln n!$

$\ln L = -\ln n + 2\ln 2n -2 - \ln n + 1\\
\ln L = 2\ln 2 - 1\\
L = 4e^{-1}$